# Total page number while conversion from HTML to PDF

Tags: c#, html, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

In `OnEndPage` I create footer like this

```
String text = "Page " + writer.PageNumber + " of ";
Phrase p1footer = new Phrase(text, baseFontNormal);
Phrase p2footer = new Phrase("Sign", baseFontNormal);
iTextSharp.text.Image LogoImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(img);

//Create PdfTable object
PdfPTable pdfTabFooter = new PdfPTable(3);

//We will have to create separate cells to include image logo and 2 separate strings
//Row 1
PdfPCell pdfCellf1 = new PdfPCell(p1footer);
PdfPCell pdfCellf2 = new PdfPCell(p2footer);
PdfPCell pdfCellf3 = new PdfPCell(LogoImg);

//set the alignment of all three cells and set border to 0
pdfCellf1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfCellf2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
pdfCellf3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;

pdfCellf1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
pdfCellf2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
pdfCellf3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;

pdfCellf1.Border = 0;
pdfCellf2.Border = 0;
pdfCellf3.Border = 0;

//add all three cells into PdfTable
pdfTabFooter.AddCell(pdfCellf1);
pdfTabFooter.AddCell(pdfCellf2);
pdfTabFooter.AddCell(pdfCellf3);

pdfTabFooter.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width;
pdfTabFooter.WidthPercentage = 70;

pdfTabFooter.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, document.PageSize.GetBottom(50), writer.DirectContent);
```

in concert with

```
public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

    //ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(total, Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE, new Phrase((writer.PageNumber).ToString()), 40, 2, 0);

    footerTemplate.BeginText();
    footerTemplate.SetFontAndSize(bf, 12);
    footerTemplate.SetTextMatrix(40, 2);
    footerTemplate.ShowText((writer.PageNumber).ToString());
    footerTemplate.EndText();
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
    using (var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 80, 60))
    {
        //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
        {
            writer.PageEvent = new Common.Classes.iTextEvents;
            //Open the document for writing                                                
            doc.Open();
            //Create a new HTMLWorker bound to our document                        
            using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(css)))
            {
                using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTML)))
                {
                    doc.NewPage();
                    //Parse the HTML
                    iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                }
            }
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Main problem here is it does not show total pagenumber after `1 of`..am I missing something? any suggestion?

Comment: Not meant as an answer to your question, but I don't see you doing any HTML to PDF conversion in your code so I don't know if that is relevant?

Comment: Great! I noticed that your comment mentions `HTMLWorker` but your code actually uses `XMLWorker` so you might want to change your comment.

Comment: ok so changing to HTMLWorker it will give me output as I want right? @AmedeeVanGasse.. will it render exactly like HTML in pDF?

Comment: That is *not* what I wrote. You should not use `HTMLWorker`, it is deprecated.

Comment: can you suggest me what should I do now?

Comment: I suggest that you wait until someone else gives you an answer to your question about the missing total page number in the footer of your page, because I am currently unable to answer that question.

Comment: lol thank you :) @AmedeeVanGasse.. its actually coming but I couldn't set in the table..only that I want to know..